# Moving files between two locations constantly

Tags: powershell, batch-file, file-transfer

I have few files that will require moving between two servers over the network. The UNC paths will be \server\c$... and same on the other server.

I am looking for a script or a piece of software that would do this. I know I can use PowerShell or robocopy but I would like something that would monitor the location and if file shows up it would move it.

I would also need to put a delay on the file move once a file is detected - as in 'oh there is a file there *waits 5 seconds* *moves the file*'.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Edit: managed to sort this by creating an .exe from the PowerShell script, provided by Drew, with PS EXE app and using NSSM to create a service from it.

Comment: And why not use the `/MOT:` option from `Robocopy`?

Comment: @Squashman I could not find whether Robocopy could have a delay before moving the file and whether it could be setup so the cmd window wouldn't have to be opened on the screen all time. I was leaning more towards powershell as I have used that more than Robocopy and .bat scripts....

Comment: Yes. The help file for `ROBOCOPY` is quite daunting. I will admit that I myself have glanced over a few of its options and find out later on from a colleague that it could do something I didn't know it could do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, please try and create some code yourself next time. Even if it was some `Get-ChildItem` while loop.

This will monitor the the folder location `$watcher.path` for any new `"Created"` events and roughly 5 seconds after the event. I am unsure where I pilfered it from but it has come in handy for a long time.

It will only monitor NEW events and not previous events. So if the folder has some files in it, it will only run the action on newly created / modified files depending on your action.

```
# Set folder and files to watch and misc flags
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\Source\Location"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

# Define actions to be taken when an event is detected
$action = {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $Last = 1
    $Current = (Get-Item $path).length
    while ($Current -ne $Last) {
        $Last = $Current
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        $Current = (Get-Item $path).length
    }
    # Change x if you want to increase the time before the move
    #sleep x
    Move-Item -Path $path -Destination "C:\Destination\Location"
}

# Decide which events to watch
# Changed, Created, Deleted, Renamed events.
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
while ($true) {sleep 5}
```